# Using histogram equalization for 3 regions in histogram

Tags: matlab, range, histogram, octave, histogram-equalization

I'm trying to develop an application that will stretching the histogram for each region..

In one picture, the histogram will be divided into 3 region which are dark, mid and bright region.
the range will be: [0 85], [85 171] and [171 255]

my problem is, how to write a code to use histogram equalization on each region separately and after that, the result will be in one histogram and show one image too.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
r = randn(1000,1);
[N,X] = hist(r,30);

lowLim = -1;
highLim = 1;

L1 = X<lowLim;
L2 = X>highLim;

figure
hold on
bar(X,N)
bar(X(L1),N(L1),'k')
bar(X(L2),N(L2),'r')
```

[image: colored region histogram]

Comment: thank you for the answer.. the concept is correct, but how I can apply it for an image that i choose where the histogram will has range [0 255]..? the image will be histeq after converting into grayscale(rgb2gray)?